# Alias for a function name has a different type signature. Why?

Tags: haskell, types

```
import Data.List (genericLength)

len = genericLength

:t genericLength
genericLength :: (Num i) => [b] -> i
:t len
len :: [b] -> Integer
```

Why is the type of `len` different from type of `genericLength`? The intent here is to use a shorter alias for `genericLength`.

Aren't functions first-class in haskell? Shouldn't giving another name for a function result in an identical function?

Comment: I don't know enough about this to post an answer, but I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the [Monomorphism Restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). If you put `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` at the top of the file, it will behave the way you expect it to.

Comment: +1 to Jeffrey for saying that it is related to Monomorphism restriction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're seeing here is because of a requirement that top-level declarations *with no arguments* be *monomorphic*. You can find [some discussion of the reasons for this on the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction), and some information about [controlling this behavior](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/monomorphism.html) in the GHC user's guide.

As illustration, note that giving `len` an argument fixes the problem:

```
len x = genericLength x

> :t len
len :: Num i => [b] -> i
```

So does giving it a type signature:

```
len :: (Num b) => [a] -> b
len = genericLength
```

And so does turning off the monomorphism restriction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Data.List (genericLength)

len = genericLength

> :t len
len :: Num i => [b] -> i
```

In this specific case, I think you're also getting a different type (rather than a compiler error) because of *defaulting* rules that specify that certain type classes should default to specific types (in this case, `Num` defaults to `Integer`. If you try doing the same thing with `fmap` you get this:

```
> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( MonoTest.hs, interpreted )

MonoTest.hs:4:5:
    Ambiguous type variable `f0' in the constraint:
      (Functor f0) arising from a use of `fmap'
    Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
      f :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f0 a -> f0 b
        (bound at MonoTest.hs:4:1)
    Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
                  or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
    In the expression: fmap
    In an equation for `f': f = fmap
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

You can find some information about defaulting in the [Haskell 98 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4). I'll also mention that GHC supports an extended form of defaulting that's mostly used for GHCi (and is enabled there by default), which occasionally confuses people.

Comment: @gorlum0: Hahahaha, monomorphism and defaulting certainly make that function *especially* unhelpful.

Comment: Note that shouldn't happen anymore from GHC 7.8 as "the monomorphism restriction is now turned off by default in GHCi". (https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.1-rc1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-8-1.html)